# Excel Spreadsheet online with formulas?

Tags: php, excel, spreadsheet, formula

I have been given an excel spreadsheet with a price calculator and the task to create a web interface to emulate this.

Is there a simple way of getting the functionality and formulas from the spreadsheet in to an online form and format?

Comment: Import into one of the online Office suites perhaps?

Comment: Or try to import the worksheet to Google Spreadsheet. Does the calculator works with formulas or VBA?

Comment: If it is a one-time only shot, i'd say: check out the formulas and reproduce them. If they update it and then you want to sync yours, then find out an online equivalent.

Comment: From what I can see it looks like formulas in the shape of a lot of vlookups

Comment: 25 sheets within the workbook to make one 'frontend'

Comment: If I try to upload to Google docs it tells me: "This document has reached the 400,000 cell per spreadsheet limit. Create a new spreadsheet to continue working, as you may not be able to add any more rows or columns."

Comment: I'd say the *best* way is to understand the logic and try to recode something from scratch in PHP. Your VLOOKUPS will probably be no more than requests on your database

Comment: If you Google "convert excel to web" you wll get a list of packages that claim to be able to perform the conversion you require.  However, I suspect JMax is correct and your best option is to transfer the data from the background worksheets to a MySQL database with a PHP front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a library like http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ can help you to extract the relevant information/logic.